# Why does a java.lang.String not equal a hardcoded String?

Tags: java

I've been developing for a CraftBukkit Minecraft server. This gives me a good API to work with. This API includes the `onCommand` method, which allows me to implement new commands.

I've just been trying to do that, but when I send a command such as `/example arg0`, for some reason I can't compare with `arg0` from my code. I'm trying to check for when `args[0] == "on"`, yet although `args` and `args[0]` are both defined and I set `args[0]` to "on", the comparison still returns false.

```
private CBPlugin pluginReference;

public NerfTntExecutor(CBPlugin plugin) {
    // (...)
    pluginReference = plugin;
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (sender.hasPermission("command.op.nerftnt")) {
        if(args.length > 0) {
            // (...)
            sender.sendMessage(args[0]);
            sender.sendMessage(args[0].getClass().getName());
            if(args[0] == "on")
                sender.sendMessage("true");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            sender.sendMessage("Not enough arguments!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        pluginReference.getLogger().info("No permission");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `sender.sendMessage` calls display the data given back to the person who sent the command. In this case, `args[0]` is displayed as "on" and `args[0].getClass().getName()` gets shown as `java.lang.String` - the type of the argument. However, the next line `if(args[0] == "on")` is false.

Why is this? I seem to be comparing a `String` to another `String`, and they both have the same contents. Why should a comparison of the two return false?

Comment: Use `.equals()` to test `String` equality, not `==`!

Comment: Because `==` is pointer equality. And as with `Object`'s two equivalent instances are not the **same** instance.

Comment: Someone want to add that as an answer?